# hash table in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, hashtable

What class can I use to associate an index in a NSMutableIndexSet to an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary`. You can use objects as it's keys.

There is also `NSHashTable`.

Comment: I've not found NSHashTable. Have you a link to doc?

Comment: Oh you're working on iOS. The `NSHashTable` is only available on Mac. Just use the dictionary.

Comment: `NSHashTable` is now available in iOS 6.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use a raw integer as the key to an object, you can use a `CFMutableDictionaryRef` instead.  This is going to drop you down a layer from Cocoa into CoreFoundation, but it'll still work just fine:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef indexMap;

indexMap = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

NSUInteger key = 42;
id value = @"The Answer";
CFDictionarySetValue(indexMap, (const void *)key, value);

id value = CFDictionaryGetValue(indexMap, (const void *)key);
CFRelease(indexMap);
```

This is really handy if you're going to be accessing this dictionary frequently and don't want to deal with a whole bunch of transient `NSNumber` objects.

(I'm ignoring that you can toll-free bridge this, because once you start mucking around with the behaviors of keys and values, you don't really want to consider this an `NSMutableDictionary` at all)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use an `NS[Mutable]Dictionary`. You can wrap the integer indexes in an `NSNumber` via `-[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:]` for the keys (this like manual boxing of primitives in Java) and add a key-value pair using `-[NSMutableDictionary addObject:forKey:]`.

Comment: An index in a NSMutableIndexSet is a **NSUInteger**. Isn't it enough for the key?

Comment: No. It needs to be an object of some sort.